# Show a pdf in android Webview with authendication

Tags: android, android-webview

I am working in an android application an I want to open a pdf from a link in an android webview. But the link has implemented authendication. I am not able to open that link with pdf.But if I place a link without the pdf, I am able to see the web page in the android webview.So the authendication works fine. The problem is when I append "https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" to the url to open the pdf.

Please look into my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        WebView webview = new WebView(MainActivity.this);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        String url=
                 "https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" +"http://spahousingli.evero.com/SPADocuments/Forms/Clients/Admissions/ADM000000011.pdf";


        webview.loadUrl(url);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view,
                    android.webkit.HttpAuthHandler handler, String host,
                    String realm) {

                handler.proceed("username", "password");
            };
        });
        setContentView(webview);

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem is that the credentials used for logging in (http header for basic authentication) are sent to the google url and Google will not send them to spahousingli.evero.com. Therefor the spahousingli.evero.com does not receive the authentication header and will reject the request from Google.

I think downloading the pdf first and opening it with Adobe Reader on you device is the easiest solutions.

**Edit:**
Download the pdf to your phone. (locationOfYourPdfFile)
Open the pdf using the following code:

```
File pdfFile = new File(locationOfYourPdfFile);
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path,"application/pdf");
pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

try{
    startActivity(pdfIntent);
}catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
    Toast.makeText(MyPDFDemo.this, "No Application available to view pdf", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.reader")));
}
```

Comment: So any solution for that ?

Comment: Yes, download the file and open it with Adobe Reader locally.