# Third party jar or sdk to open a pdf without downloading in android

Tags: android

I am working in an android application where I want to open a pdf from a web link without downloading. Is an existing Thirdy jar or sdk like this.

Comment: you can use drive api. there you can use google doc viewer

Comment: Yes, I used google doc, but my web link has implemented basic authendication, so I can't. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25153246/show-a-pdf-in-android-webview-with-authendication